# mklink /J created to "Computer"

Tags: junction, mklink

In trying to create a junction link for my iTunes backup folder, I accidentally pointed to a directory called "Computer/MediaSync"

This occurred because I forgot to use quotation marks around the directory and the Apple Computer directory has a space!

The command I used was:

```
mklink /J C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync E:\iTunes Backup
```

The response showed

> Junction created for C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Apple  <<===>> Computer\MobileSync

I tried deleting the "Apple" shortcut that was created, but I cannot recreate the junction.  When I try it is responds with "Cannot create a file when that file already exists"

I am trying to run the following and it never works.

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync" "E:\iTunes Backup"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the message states: if you have an existing directory (in this case ...\Apple Computer\MobileSync), then you can not turn it into a junction or symbolic link with the mklink command. You need to delete that folder, and then recreate it (with the same same if you wish) with the mklink command.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out and moved the actual mobilesync  directory (effectively deleting it) and then my junction worked.